# Maximum depth of a tree, using a queue

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

In the book Data Structures and Algorithms made easy by Narasimha Karumanchi,
this is the code given to find the maximum depth of a tree.

He offers a `null` to the queue for some reason. I do not understand why. Removing it breaks the code.

I want to know why the author is adding a `null` and if it is okay to solve a problem in this way, because we can solve the same problem without adding a `null`.

Source code:

```
public class MaxDepthInBinaryTreeWithLevelOrder {
// Returns the depth of this binary tree. The depth of a binary tree is the
// length of the longest path from this node to a leaf. The depth of a
// binary tree with no descendants (that is, just a leaf) is zero.
public int maxDepthLevelOrder(BinaryTreeNode root){
    if(root == null)
        return 0;
    int maxDepth = 1;
    Queue<BinaryTreeNode> q = new LinkedList<BinaryTreeNode>();
    q.offer(root);
    q.offer(null);   //  <----------- 'NULL' added Here
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        BinaryTreeNode tmp = q.poll();
        if(tmp != null){
            if(tmp.getLeft() != null)
                q.offer(tmp.getLeft());
            if(tmp.right != null)
                q.offer(tmp.right);
        }else{
            if(!q.isEmpty()){
                ++maxDepth;
                q.offer(null); //  <--------- Here
            }
        }
    }
    return maxDepth;
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this algorithm (maybe if I spent more time on it I could figure out), but it appears he's using `null` as some sort of marker.

Comment: I think it's a breadth first search.  The algorithm searches across the width of the tree.  A `null` marks the end of each width, so when a `null` is found the depth counter is incremented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

null is used for marking the end of a level.

The author is using level order traversal to find the depth of the tree. He uses Queue data structure to achieve it.  To demarcate levels next to each other null is used as level marker.

For eg. He first inserts root, then null marker. In while loop first iteration, first element from queue is removed and it's left and right  children if not null are added to the queue. When next element is removed, it will be null denoting the end of level 1. Now if the queue is not empty there could be many other levels. So null marker is inserted again.

Note:- whenever null is element being removed from the queue, it means that there are no more elements in current level and all its children in next level are added to queue and no more elements in the next level are remaining. So we can insert the null marker again to mark the end of next level.

Answer (score 0):

As Queue traverse the Binary search in Breath first way i.e. cover all elements which are at same level of depth and then move on to the next level of depth.

**null** is added to the queue after all elements (present at same level of depth) is added to queue.

Removing **null** from queue is an indicator that we have successfully traversed all elements present at same level of depth and that's why we increase the maxDepth counter.

null can be seen as flag to let the algorithm know that yes we have covered all the elements which are present at same level of depth .